# Flag .. it doesn't belong here .. off-topic does not let me flag articles to move to other sites on Stack Exchange

Tags: support, migration

Here's an example of a [TeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX) question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881047/change-latex-section-fonts

This probably should be on the TeX site:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/

But when I go to flag the article, it only allows me to choose between a few sites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's **really** clear where it belongs just flag the post for moderator attention and use the

> "**it needs ♦ moderator attention** > other" option

giving the site you think the question belongs on in the message.

Voting to close as "off topic" may result in the question being closed before it could be migrated.

Comment: Close as offtopic is still less messy than migration

Comment: @random - true, but I've seen questions where the OP has simply got the wrong site. Migration in those cases is the best option.

Comment: It's less a hassle to migrate after a bungled off topic than the other way around. Get that wrong, it's obliterated across the network.

Comment: Is this really the correct way to flag for migration? The "It doesn't belong here" option really seems like the most obvious option to select if you think that the question belongs somewhere else. How are new or even experienced users supposed to know this? Telling users to "read the FAQ" or "search on meta" is all very well, but most people don't/won't/haven't and these are really just excuses for an interface that could be much more intuitive with some simple improvement. Rather than tell people "RTFM", let's eliminate the need for a manual all together.

Comment: @jhabbott - Yes, this is the correct way to flag for migration. In most cases, questions that are off-topic should just be closed. If they're exemplary questions, then a moderator can decide if he or she wants to discuss the issue with the target site's mods and send it over. This is the exeption, not the norm.

Answer (score -1):

On another question. (I don't know which one) a few mods and Jeff said there can only be five (5) sites that can be on the off-topic list. To move it to another site just select off-topic and then add an comment saying where it should be moved and the mods should move it to the site that you want.