# Marking a Question for Migration

Tags: support, flags, migration, migrated-questions

I currently came across a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553080/probability-hit-bullseye) on SO that would be a clear cut candidate to migrate to a different SE site.  My question, as a newer SO user who is looking to help keep the community clean of out of place questions, what are the correct steps I should take to mark this for Migration?

- Is there a specific flag I should use so a moderator can see/move the post?
- Should I comment in the post to the user, and have them try and migrate it? (seems wrong, since they might not go through the trouble after OPing in the wrong place anyway)
- Something else I don't know of?

I ended up commenting and flagging the post as "needing mod attention" and marked as "other" in which I provided the detail that I thought the post should be migrated.  I know the mods have a lot on their plate already, so anything I can do to help them out is nice, I just need to know what the proper steps are to "request a post for migration".

NOTE: If this isn't something in place to handle these situations from a non-admin/mod POV (someone like myself), could this be a new feature to be added, a "Flag: mark for migration"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You close as off-topic, then you flag it as 'Other' and let the moderator know which site it should be migrated to.

This is a [feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160929/add-flag-as-other-checkbox-to-vote-to-close-as-off-topic-dialog) to get that functionality combined.

Comment: The OP can't vote to close (lacks privs). On the same token, he of course can't flag as off-topic and then flag as other because you can't flag twice.

Comment: Right, you have to use 'Other' if you want to leave a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Flag -> it doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate -> off-topic:

[image: a]

Comment: Unless the migration destination in mind is **not** on the off-topic list.

Comment: @Walls You can't add a comment to an off-topic flag; you can't vote to close and then flag and comment (as Lance suggested in his answer), because you don't have enough rep to close; and you can't flag as off-topic, and then flag as other, because you can't flag twice... not much you can do other than flag as off-topic and write a comment on the main question.