# Off-Topic Stack Exchange Site Selector should allow search rather than fixed list

Tags: feature-request

I came across this question this morning [Atmega8 necessary circuit for standalone working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18427864/atmega8-necessary-circuit-for-standalone-working) which should have been posted to [Electronics SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com)

When attempting to vote closed due to off-topic -> belongs on another SE site I could only select from a fixed list of 4 sites, none of which were applicable.

Can we update the selector to allow for browse/search for the appropriate site.

Comment: Careful - there are thousands of requests to add more migration targets, and the community does get a bit tired of them.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but this was specifically to allow an alternate option, rather than having to mess around finding an alternate method to close the question ... it's simply bad user experience for those helping to clean up [SO]

Comment: How is that any different from [all these other questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/96205)?

Comment: OK fair point ... but if there are that many questions on meta regarding this issue it would be nice if something was actually done about it. Voting closed on my own question

Comment: So, the thinking is, because lots of people have asked, it should be implemented regardless of the objections that have been made? I don't think so. It might help to follow some of those links and read the answers that have been given.

Comment: OK, this is what I'm looking for http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187824/166536 now how do we make it happen before the machines rise up and take over

Comment: The truth is, we're kind of hoping to *discourage* migration requests altogether. Most of the questions that people flag for migration are not actually suitable to be migrated: either because they're not actually off-topic for the site on which they're asked (questions aren't migrated just because they are a *better* fit for some other site), because they're too old, and/or because they are poor quality questions in the first place (other sites have complained that Stack Overflow was dumping its garbage on them). So making migration a more prominent option in the UI is unlikely to happen.

Comment: @CodyGray thank you for taking the time to distill this into something more insightful.  I still feel that the quality of the question is a matter for the mods and users on the site to which it is migrated and that it would be better UX for everybody concerned, however I appreciate that inter-site politics have to be considered.  I'll leave it at that.

Comment: @Merlin: the #1 rule for migrations is [don't migrate crap](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82941/please-dont-migrate-low-quality-questions-to-other-sites). Dumping poor questions on other sites is simply bad manners. And we, from experience, collectively, have no clue as to what "good question" means for other sites.

Comment: Well, that's the thing. It *is* a question for the mods and users on the site to which it is migrated. But you're not asking them. The flag is raised for moderators on the site you're flagging. How should they know what another community thinks about the question? Things start getting really complicated really quickly if you want to involve moderators from multiple sites. What if they're not active on the sites at the same time—e.g. different time zones, etc. There aren't many high quality questions that get asked on the wrong site. It's easier just to ask in the right place to start with.