# Migration options for flagging posts on unix.stackexchange

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flags, migration

Reference: [How can I tell if Comcast is blocking access to an IP?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/426480/how-can-i-tell-if-comcast-is-blocking-access-to-an-ip)

I wanted to support a commentator who pointed out that the question was off-topic for the Unix site and should be better put on either SuperUser or ServerFault. However, when performing the steps to flag the question, the only two migration options were "stackexchange" and "meta.unix".

Maybe offer a wider choice of migration options? It could be a selection box from all StackExchange sites, which would cover all possible options.

**EDIT:** Questions [More options when flagging for migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration) and [Add "Flag as Other" checkbox to "Vote to Close as Off-Topic" dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160929/add-flag-as-other-checkbox-to-vote-to-close-as-off-topic-dialog/187824#187824) don't present a clear resolution and final guidance, and the voted proposals have clearly not been adopted.

Comment: If anything, it is not a bug.

Comment: @rene or a bug by design. :)

Comment: The "status-declined" tag provides a pretty clear resolution... Anyway, if you want one site to add to their migration paths, you need to be asking on **that site**... not on MSE. You'll have to explain why the target site should be possible and prove that it's necessary - meaning there's a large number of questions moved there regularly.

Comment: @Catija and others Please read the comments to Robert Cartaino's answer below, to see how the answers to other questions still leave the issue unresolved.

Comment: The marked dupe has [tag:status-declined]. That means, "yes, we considered this, no, this is not happening, and you'll need to present *substantial*, *new* evidence for why this would be a good idea for it to be reconsidered". The clear resolution therefore is "No". The final guidance is "flag moderators if it's absolutely critical" (and, reading between the lines a bit, "just close otherwise"). The voted proposals have not been adopted and are not at all likely to be, and simply raising the same points again will only make the situation *less* favorable if anything.

Answer (score 3):

Migrations are no longer the preferred way move a new question when you can simply re-ask it in the context of the *correct* site. Migrations have a lot of side effects, so they should only be used when there are significant answers that would be a shame to lose in the transition.

Moving a question mechanically *bypasses* the in-question dupe checking and it may not fit the rules of the new site. The question may need to be framed differently because you are asking it of a different community (who may also have their own guidance regarding content). The tags will likely be wrong; every site has their own tags. The voting won't likely match the expertise of that site (particularly if it was down-voted for asking on the wrong site). Often the comments left behind reflect the question being out of place, and any comments (or answers) already posted will likely be orphaned if the authors do not have an account on the other site.

We try not to use migrations much anymore. Migrations need an overhaul regarding how and when it works properly. When there is little content to save, the author should simply re-ask the question on the correct site.

Comment: Your answer addressed what is no longer the preferred method of closing the question as off-topic - so what should be done in the referenced case to close the question?

Comment: @user1404316 "re-ask" means "delete on the original site where it was posted, and post again on the other site". So closing isn't relevant, it should be *deleted* on the site where it's off topic.

Comment: Getting there... OK, so who does the deletion? What's the process? Flag it? There isn't an option to "flag for deletion" as far I can see.

Comment: @user1404316 the OP does both the re-post and the deletion. The OP has a delete link for their own posts. This does assume the question has not yet upvoted answers.

Comment: That's a useless substitute for the migration or flagging procedures, which are done by people other than the OP. The whole point is that people other than the OP are judging the question!