# Why is there not a choice to request questions to be moved to another stackexchange group?

Tags: discussion

Regularly I see questions, that do not belong in the correct stack exchange group.

For e.g. duplicates, you can close a question and add a duplicate of the link.

However, sometimes a question belongs to a different stack exchange group, and there is no way except to flag the question and ask it to be moved.

Wouldn't it be more efficient to move it? It could even be voted upon by users.

(example: [What is the most suitable AI technique to use?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/17200/what-is-the-most-suitable-ai-technique-to-use))

Comment: Related and/or dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190430/155739

Comment: There does exist a way for normal users to move (migrate) questions between sites; see [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica True, thanks for the link

Comment: @SonictheReinstateMonica-hog Same remark as above. Thanks!

Comment: @SonictheReinstateMonica-hog Thanks for the link! Not sure if it is intended, but migrating is neither obvious nor easy nor even possible to anywhere but the site meta in 3 cases tested. I tested politics.se, parenting.se and medical sciences.se. It took 3-4 mostly non obvious menu choices. Without your tip it would not occur to some users to even test this menu sequence. Finally I could not find any other non meta site among the choices to migrate to. Should this maybe go into a different question on se.meta?

Comment: Your site is a beta site, which doesn't have migration paths set up like graduated sites do. Sadly, there is no option but to flag for a moderator to migrate every time, as the SE team has decided not to implement migration options for beta sites.